# Git remote repo no showing in <ul>

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, html, github-api

I am trying to list my github repos through their api but its not showing up on my page but by using the exact same code its working here on [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nT5wY/258/)

Debugging shows that the script is being called but its just not loading in its `<div>`:

```
<div id="repos">
     <ul id="repo_list">
     </ul>
</div>`
```

Here is the markup in my source code:

```
<section id="git-hub">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="box">
            <div class="center">
                <h2>GitHub</h2>
                <p class="lead">Go on! Take a look through my repos!</p>
                <div id="repos">
                    <ul id="repo_list">
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div id="repo_content"></div>
                <script>
                        $.ajax({
                            type: "GET",
                            url: "https://api.github.com/users/google/repos",
                            dataType: "json",
                            success: function(result) {
                                for( i in result ) {
                                    $("#repo_list").append(
                                            "<li><a href='" + result[i].html_url + "' target='_blank'>" +
                                            result[i].name + "</a></li>"
                                    );
                                    console.log("i: " + i);
                                }
                                console.log(result);
                                $("#repo_count").append("Total Repos: " + result.length);
                            }
                        });
                </script>
            </div><!--/.center-->          
        </div>
    </div>
</section><!--/#pricing-->
```

Does anybody know what could be the reason?

Comment: Where in the HTML file are you loading your jQuery?

Comment: at the bottom just before the </body> tag

Comment: Try putting this `script` tag below your jQuery.

Comment: dammit thanks your right. put this as an answer and ill accept it. thankyou

Comment: Made it into an answer. Glad to help.

Comment: its the little things that catch you out, i thought it was a more sophisticated problem than just the pos of a script!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're putting this `script` tag above where you're loading your jQuery. Place this `script` tag below where you're loading your jQuery.